# Debug Error "This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusal way"

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

That is the error i am getting in visual studio when i am running the exe(without debugging),but while debugging it is working fine.It is happening only in the case when i am opting for without debugging or running the .exe

Regards,
Siva

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it .It is the problem with my I.D.E ,I had uninstalled and installed it again and then i started the rebuilding it again and now it is working fine.